# achemso - Generating an asterisk in front of "E-mail:"

Tags: achemso

Is it possible to add an asterisk before the word "E-mail" when using achemso. This is an example document I have.

```
\documentclass[journal=jcisd8,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use modern font encodings
\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{The author}
\email{theauthor@somelab.abc}
\affiliation[somelab]{Some Lab, Some City, Some Country}

\title[An \textsf{achemso} demo]
  {This is a manuscript}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this generates this page -

[image: Result of compilation]

The journal needs an asterisk in front of the word "E-mail" (i.e. ***E-mail: theauthor@somelab.abc**). How can I achieve that? I cannot find anything relevant (at least as far as I can tell) in achemso manual.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have an official request from an editorial office, please forward it to me (`joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk`)

Comment: @JosephWright This was an official request from the editorial office. But, I will have to check with my higher ups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite a strange request. For a single author, you can patch the relevant command.

```
\documentclass[journal=jcisd8,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use modern font encodings
\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\acs@contact@details}{E}{*\,E}{}{}
\makeatother

\author{The author}
\email{theauthor@somelab.abc}
\affiliation[somelab]{Some Lab, Some City, Some Country}

\title[An \textsf{achemso} demo]
  {This is a manuscript}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer!