# achemso - asterisk in front of "Email:" and separate lines for each corresponding author

Tags: achemso, email

We use achemso to write our manuscript. We have 2 corresponding authors, the emails of which are, by default, listed as

```
Email: correspondingAuthor1@abc.aa; correspondingAuthor2@xyz.zz
```

We were required by the editor to list the emails as follows:

```
*Email: correspondingAuthor1@abc.aa
*Email: correspondingAuthor2@xyz.zz
```

(note the asterisk and the new line)

We found the following answer to fix it for one corresponding author only:

[achemso - Generating an asterisk in front of "E-mail:"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467844/achemso-generating-an-asterisk-in-front-of-e-mail)

but could not find a solution that will work for 2 authors and give the desired result. Could anybody help us?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs a second patch.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[journal=jcisd8,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage{chemformula} % Formula subscripts using \ch{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use modern font encodings    

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % needed for patch
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\acs@contact@details}{E}{*\,E}{}{}
\patchcmd{\acs@email@list@aux}{;}{\par*\,Email}{}{} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatother

\author{Fred T.Firstauthor}
\affiliation{Current address: Some other place}
\email{groupleader@unknown.uu}
\author{Second Bloke}
\email{correspondingAuthor1@abc.aa}
\affiliation[University of Sometown]
{University of Somewhere, Sometown, USA}
\author{Indus Trialguy}
\email{correspondingAuthor2@abc.aa}
\affiliation[SponsoCo]
{Research Department, SponsorCo, BigCity, USA}


\title[An \textsf{achemso} demo]
{This is a manuscript}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{abstract}
    \kant[1]
    \end{abstract}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.